# compare 2 lists with one having null values

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a class

```
public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to find the users with a particular value of code

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();

users.Add(new User() { id = 1, code="A"});
users.Add(new User() { id = 2, code = null });
users.Add(new User() { id = 3, code = "C" });
users.Add(new User() { id = 4, code = "C" });
users.Add(new User() { id = 5, code = "B" });

string[] possibleValues = new string[] { null, "A", "B" };

var result = users
  .Where(u => possibleValues
                .Any(l => l.Equals(u.code)))
  .ToList();
```

I get `NullReferenceException` because `possibleValues` has `null` in it. I understand that. Can someone suggest a better way of doing it.

Comment: Here you can simply use the `==` operator. When looking in the [String code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/string.cs) then the `==` operator has this code: `public static bool operator == (String a, String b) {
           return String.Equals(a, b);
        }`. So this code `possibleValues.Any(l => l == u.code)` will work just fine.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I figured this out after looking at Dmitry's answer. However. I prefer his answer because that gives me the flexibility of adding StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase

Comment: Ok, in that case you really need to call `string.Equals` static method directly because `==` operator on `string` performs `an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're comparing `string`s, that's why I suggest changing `l.Equals(...)` to `string.Equals(...)` which is aware how to deal with `null`s:

```
  ...
  // string.Equals(l, u.code):
  //   do l and u.code equal? i.e. are they both nulls 
  //   or do they contain the equal strings 
  var result = users
    .Where(u => possibleValues.Any(l => string.Equals(l, u.code)))
    .ToList();
```

Please, notice, that you can *tune* `string.Equals` if you want, e.g.
`string.Compare(l, u.code, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Where` with `Any` and add filters to ignore *null* values like this:-

```
var result = users.Where(x => possibleValues
               .Any(z => z == x.code && (z != null || x.code != null)));
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on discussion with @Dmitry (which makes sense to me) you can simplify it like this:-

```
var result = users.Where(x => possibleValues.Any(z => z == x.code));
```

[Working Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sr9kxi)

Comment: Hope that He have included `null` in `possibleValues` to get item with id `2` in the result But your code does not includes that in the output

Comment: @un-lucky - But OP never mentioned that, if he really wants `2` as well. Though it need a tiny fix: `x.code == null` instead of `x.code != null` :)

Comment: Aren't we going to obtain *three* `user`s, not *two* with codes `"A"`, `"B"` and **null**? Your Fiddle demo returns codes `1` and `5` only when code `2` has been expected as well.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - Yes in my second comment I clarified that only, but OP never mentioned he need record with id `2` as well.

Comment: @Rahul Singh: if `OP` doesn't want the instance with `id == 2` (with `code == null`) why `possibleValues` contains `null`? More naturally put it as `possibleValues = new string[] { "A", "B" };` (I want two users with "A" and "B" codes)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `object.ReferenceEquals` instead for `l.Equals`. In you case when `l` is null in the iteration it doesn't contains the definition for `.Equals()` and that causing the error. you can try the same by using the following code:

```
users.Where(u => possibleValues.Any(l => object.ReferenceEquals(l,u.code))).ToList();
```

Above code will give you the items with IDs `1`,`2` and `5` in the example.

Comment: Why the down vote. I was actually contemplating using this

Comment: @RajatMalik: Usually I'm getting downs because of personal revenge, forget about that. Happy to help you

Comment: @un-lucky +1 for `object.ReferenceEquals();`.

Comment: Instead of object.ReferenceEquals, if I use == over here, won't I get the same response.

Comment: `code` `"A"` within some `user` instance is not necessary *referentialy equals* (i.e. share the same referece) to `string` within `possibleValues` array (depends on string *Interning*). Sorry, but your code is dangerous

Comment: One way is to spin up the default equality comparer for the type `l` and use that instead, so `EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(left, right)`, which handles null and should provide the same semantics as `left.Equals(right)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This u can remove the null value from this code

```
var result = users.Where( y=> possibleValues
               .Any(u => u == y.code && (u != null || y.code != null)));
```

Comment: `x` is replaced with `y` and `z` with `u` any other difference with Rahul's answer?

Comment: Did you downvote him because of his comment? Not ethical.

Comment: @JojiThomasEapen: But you have casted 18 downvotes as per [records](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6412888/joji-thomas-eapen?tab=summary#user-panel-votes)

Comment: @un-lucky i have up voted ur answer only, so dont make angry on me.. if any thing else thanks